# "bundle exec rake db:test:prepare" vs "bundle exec rake db:populate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm going through Michael Hartl's tutorial and I'm unsure what the difference between these 2 commands is. Generally, in the tutorial, there's always 3 steps.

```
1. bundle exec rake db:reset
```

This makes sense, to reset the databse.

```
2. bundle exec rake db:populate
```

I figure this is to populate the database with the sample data.

```
3. bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

Why is this command still needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two commands execute on your `development` database by default, unless you specified a `RAILS_ENV`.

`rake db:test:prepare` performs all the migrations on the `test` database.

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html).

Comment: For clarification `rake db:test:prepare` checks if any migrations need to be run (and stops if they do), it then sets up your test database from a dump of your schema (a .rb or a .sql file depending on your application). That dump is created by other tasks that you will have run to set up your development database.